# Como puedo utilizar "let" fuera de un bloque en javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript, ecmascript-6

Estoy experimentando con JavaScript y me topé con esto del ámbito de variables en JavaScript, principalmente con `let`, que está integrada en ECMAscript 6.

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un prompt que solicita al usuario su edad y la compara en un `if` si es mayor que 18 le muestra la página, aunque lo sé no es muy seguro eso pero sólo es de prueba.

El código es este:

```js
/*Programador: Sommer0123
Version del codigo: 1.0
*/

//Este comportamiento cambia, cuando usamos la declaración let introducida en ECMAScript 6.
var user = prompt("Escribe tu edad: ");

if (user==18) {
    //me muestra este mensaje si es true
    let y = "Bienvenido usuario"+user;
    //aqui va el codigo que te manda a la pagina correspondiente (por privacidad la quite)
}else{

    alert("error usted no es mayor de edad");

}

/*mi problema es esta aqui que no me muestra el valor y*/
document.write(y);
```

¿Solución posible que estoy pensando? Utilizar un `switch` para comparar la edad, pero se me hace mucho código.

Comment: Disculpa la fuente de todo esto la saque de aqui:[enlace](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types)

Answer (score 1):

creo que estas un poco confundido con la condicional, y sobre el let lo declaras arriba para que su ambiente sea total

```js
/*Programador: Sommer0123
Version del codigo: 1.0
*/

//Este comportamiento cambia, cuando usamos la declaración let introducida en ECMAScript 6.
var user = prompt("Escribe tu edad: ");
let y;
if (user>=18) {
    //me muestra este mensaje si es true
     y = "Bienvenido usuario"+user;
    //aqui va el codigo que te manda a la pagina correspondiente (por privacidad la quite)
}else{

    alert("error usted no es mayor de edad");

}

/*mi problema es esta aqui que no me muestra el valor y*/
document.write(y);
```

si usas var, el var 'y' sobrevivira bloque tras bloque, cuidado con su uso
aca te dejo un ejemplo

```js
/*Programador: Sommer0123
Version del codigo: 1.0
*/

//Este comportamiento cambia, cuando usamos la declaración let introducida en ECMAScript 6.
var user = prompt("Escribe tu edad: ");

if (user>=18) {
    //me muestra este mensaje si es true
     var y = "Bienvenido usuario"+user;
    //aqui va el codigo que te manda a la pagina correspondiente (por privacidad la quite)
}else{

    alert("error usted no es mayor de edad");

}

/*mi problema es esta aqui que no me muestra el valor y*/
document.write(y);
```

Comment: Ups disculpa creeo que si tienes razon sobre la condicional se me olvido ajaja disculpame pero en esa estaba pensando..  y gracias el codigo funciona correctamente ,pero mi problema es eso sobre que let es local ?? como? segun yo y lo que se de javascript es que cuando no le estableces "var" es local mientras este en una funcion  ?

Comment: y creo que el codigo es mas legible y mas entendido asi:*/
var edad = prompt("Escribe tu edad: ");
var user = prompt("Escribe tu nuevo user");
let y;
if (edad>=18) {
    //me muestra este mensaje si es true
     y = "Bienvenido  "+user+" puede acceder por que tienes "+edad  ;
    //aqui va el codigo que te manda a la pagina correspondiente (por privacidad la quite)
}else{

    alert("error usted no es mayor de edad");

}

/*mi problema es esta aqui que no me muestra el valor y*/
document.write(y);
//SOLUCION POSIBLE QUE ESTOY PENSANDO? utilizar un switch

Comment: @sommer0123 edite mi respuesta, mostrando la diferencia entre var y let

Comment: @sommer0123 no olvides marcar bien si resolvi tu problema